# splitting multiple paths in string

Tags: c#, string

I have a command, which might resemble the following:

`SYNC C:\Users\Fox Mulder\SyncClient C:\Users\Fox Mulder\SyncServer`

This is a command that will be entered via a Console Application. It will be read by Console.ReadLine.

How can I parse the command so that I can get the two seperate directory path's?

I am unable to split on space, because that will result in a split at "Fox Mulder".

How can I parse this easily?

Comment: Are these paths generated by your program, or user input, or...?

Comment: User input from an console application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
string testString = @"SYNC C:\Users\Fox Mulder\SyncClient C:\Users\Fox Mulder\SyncServer";

int firstIndex = testString.IndexOf(Path.VolumeSeparatorChar);
int secondIndex = testString.LastIndexOf(Path.VolumeSeparatorChar);
string path1, path2;

if (firstIndex != secondIndex  && firstIndex != -1)
{
    path1 = testString.Substring(firstIndex - 1, secondIndex - firstIndex);
    path2 = testString.Substring(secondIndex - 1);

    Console.WriteLine("Path 1 = " + path1);
    Console.WriteLine("Path 2 = " + path2);
}
```

Comment: Use the right tools for the right job.  If the paths are absolute and we are expecting only two, then it's good enough.  It would be easy enough to check that the parsed paths are valid, or that we get 2 and only 2 paths.

Answer (score 7):

The command should be space delimited, with each path wrapped in quotes to properly include their embedded strings:

```
SYNC "C:\Users\Fox Mulder\SyncClient" "C:\Users\Fox Mulder\SyncServer"
```

---

***If*** you can't require quotes then things become much more ugly--consider paths such as

```
c:\documents and settings\mom and dad\documents\family vacations\2009\the bahama ramas\
```

String splitting on " " will be a headache.  The brute force method would be to test the first portion of the path (c:\documents) on it's own, if it's invalid then append the next portion (c:\documents and), etc... of course it's ugly, non-performant, and full of potential issues (what if both "c:\documents" and "c:\documents and settings" are valid?  Your code will end up very skittish and paranoid.

Comment: You can't guarantee usage patterns... requiring quotes in the command line is fragile.

Comment: yet this is how most command lines behave. this is common practice

Answer (score 3):

Using `"` would solve it

```
SYNC "C:\Users\Fox Mulder\SyncClient" "C:\Users\Fox Mulder\SyncServer"
```

this will be interperted as two seperate strings in the argv

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a non-valid path character as a path delimeter.

```
SYNC C:\Users\Fox Mulder\SyncClient?C:\Users\Fox Mulder\SyncServer
```